# C# Incorrect Division of long numbers returns zero

Tags: c#, casting, division, typeconverter, int64

This is what I have on my C# code:

```
Int64 Free = Convert.ToInt64(number1); //has to be ToInt64
Int64 Size = Convert.ToInt64(number2); //has to be ToInt64
Int64 Total = (Free/Size) * 100;
```

**Free** is 35387133952 and **Size** is 64419262464

Manually dividing Free/Size I get **0.5493**

**PROBLEM**: Instead of Total return **54.93** it is returning **0**

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: integer division != floating point division. Wikipedia: [Division of Integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers)

Comment: Why does it need to be Int64?

Comment: I'm sure this is duplicated somewhere here (perhaps not with `Int64` but...)

Comment: If you need to stick with `Int64`,  try `(Free * 100) / Size`

Comment: What type are `number1` and `number2`? Since you are casting them to integers

Comment: I will answer my own question: I had to use double and when doing so it worked :-)

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to divide two integers. This is expected behavior.

If you need to get a floating point answer, you need to cast the values to floating point:

```
double Total = ((double)Free/(double)Size) * 100;
```

Comment: For the record, you only _need_ to cast one of the variables. But this is a minor point.

Comment: @gunr2171 That is true.

Comment: yes, as I answered above: I will answer my own question: I had to use double and when doing so it worked :-)

Answer (score 2):

you are dividing ints so you get an int back.

If free and size need to be int64's you can convert them to floats or doubles ect like so..

```
double total = ((double)Free/(double)Size) * 100
```

but there is no way to store 54.93 into an int .. so Total cannot be an int

Comment: yes, as I answered above: I will answer my own question: I had to use double and when doing so it worked :-)